# How do I set a node's attribute with Mojo::DOM?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to set an attribute with Mojo::DOM like so:

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my $a = Mojo::DOM->new('<a></a>');
my $a = $a->attr({ 'href' => 'https://foo/bar' });
print $a;
```

I would expect it to print

```
<a href="https://foo/bar"></a>
```

but I get

```
<a></a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to [find and return](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#at) the element first, for which the attribute gets changed

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new('<a></a>');

$dom->at('a')->attr({ 'href' => 'https://foo/bar' });

say $dom;
```

This is needed as there is no "attribute" for the whole tree.  As [docs say](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#NODES-AND-ELEMENTS) in the beginning

> While all node types are represented as `Mojo::DOM` objects, some methods like `attr` and `namespace` only apply to elements.

("*elements*" being nodes of the type "tag", see the link)

Comment: Works, thanks! But why? They're both Mojo::DOM objects... (BTW - typo in the code : instead of ;)

Comment: @simone They are, indeed -- but I guess the tree just doesn't have an "attribute."  Added to answer what the docs say about it.

Comment: In DOM terms, `$dom` is a *document* node and `$dot->at('a')` is an *element* node. Only elements have attributes.